# Why facebook webhook page feed not receiving test user events while in development

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

Steps I have taken:

I have created a Facebook App with the status "In Development"

Created Webhook, subscribed to Page>Feed. APPID/subscriptions response is

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "object": "page",
      "callback_url": "https://example.com/webhook/",
      "active": true,
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "feed",
          "version": "v3.2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I can receive sample feed field update from dashboard!

```
Dashboard webhook page shows red warning "Applications will only be able to receive test webhooks sent from the app dashboard while they are in development. No production data, including that of app admins, developers, and testers, will be delivered unless the app is live."
```

Created Test Users and granted permissions manage_pages, publish_pages

Subscribed to the Test Page created by Test User. 
TESTPAGEID/subscribed_apps  response is {success: true}

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Business",
      "link": "https://example.com/",
      "name": "Application Name",
      "id": "<APPID>",
      "subscribed_fields": [
        "feed"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when I post, like, and comment on Test Page, it doesn't receive any updates. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to submit your app for review. When Facebook accepts your review, the webhook will start working on your page (if the page is subscribed to your app).

Comment: To submit for review they are asking for the working product, for that, at least I want to make a test connection

Comment: I submitted a review for the manage_pages permission last week. I used a screencast with a sample sent from the webhook settings page and how the my app reacts to it. Facebook accepted the submission, so I guess if you can make a submission and explain how the app will work without showing the final product.